# Moving documents from one folder to another

Tags: vba

I'm looking to move a list of word documents from one folder to another. I have the list of the exact names. I found a VBA code in one of the other answers here but with that code I can only move all .doc files or one named file at a time. Any idea how I can list the names of the files I want to move in the code? Thanks in advance!

```vb
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim sourceFolderPath As String, destinationFolderPath As String
Dim FSO As Object, sourceFolder As Object, file As Object
Dim fileName As String, sourceFilePath As String, destinationFilePath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sourceFolderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test move"
destinationFolderPath = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Test"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sourceFolder = FSO.Getfolder(sourceFolderPath)

For Each file In sourceFolder.Files
    fileName = file.Name
    If InStr(fileName, ".DOC") Then ' Only doc files will be moved
        sourceFilePath = file.Path
        destinationFilePath = destinationFolderPath & "\" & fileName
        FSO.MoveFile Source:=sourceFilePath, Destination:=destinationFilePath
    End If ' If InStr(sourceFileName, ".DOC") Then' Only doc files will be moved
Next

'Don't need set file to nothing because it is initialized in for each loop 
'and after this loop is automatically set to Nothing
Set sourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Match to test the filename against your list:

```vba
Sub MoveFiles()

    Dim sourceFolderPath As String, destinationFolderPath As String
    Dim FSO As Object,  file As Object
    Dim fileName As String, rngFiles As Range

    'Adjust this line to point to wherever your list of files is...
    Set rngFiles = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Files").Range("A1:A10") 
    
    sourceFolderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test move"
    destinationFolderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" 'tw added \ here
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    For Each file In FSO.Getfolder(sourceFolderPath).Files
        fileName = file.Name
        'is the file name found in your list of files?
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(fileName, rngFiles, 0)) Then 
            file.Move destinationFolderPath 'simpler move...
        End If 
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Simplified the code a little also.

Comment: hi, 

The full I'm currently using which works is as follows:

Comment: The only changes you need are to add the first two lines from my answer, and change the `If ... Then` line as shown

Comment: I have no idea where to insert those two lines. I am a total noob at VBA. Sorry for any hassle.

Comment: hi Tim. 

I have adjusted the following as advised 
Set rngFiles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A2:A450") 

however when I open the excel file with the list of file names and run this code i get the "Run Time error 58, File already exists" and none of the files have moved. Would you be able to assist?

Comment: You'll get that error if the destination file already exists (or if you didn't add a terminating backslash to the destination folder path)  You might want to check to see if the destination file exists before you try to copy it.